# Can we Use Z3 SMT Solver for SW testing

Tags: python, z3

Can we use Z3 to do functional verification of software. For example , if i have a code which does lets say vending machine controller , can we use Z3 to functionally test it , if yes, to how much depth and if no why?

Comment: I entered your question in Bing and Google. Several useful links show up.

Answer (score 2):

Using SMT solvers for verification is both "routinely done" and is also the topic of current research in both academia and industry. And Nikolaj is being modest: I'd recommend reading his excellent and highly accessible [CACM article](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.367.9961&rep=rep1&type=pdf) to start with, which also contains many useful further references.